# query excuting problem

Tags: php, mysql

i tried to execute following query in php script.

```
$db_selected = mysql_select_db("lumiinc1_sndemo1", $con);

if ($db_selected) {    
  echo "database connected";
}
else
{
  die ("Can\'t use db : " . mysql_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO `markers` ( `name`, `address`, `lat`, `lng`, `id` ) SELECT `name`, `street`, `latitude`, `longitude`, `lid` FROM `location` WHERE NOT EXISTS ( SELECT * FROM `markers` WHERE `location`.`lid` = `markers`.`id` )";

$result = mysql_query($sql);

if ($result) {
    echo "Query executed OK";
} else {
    die("Invalid query: " . mysql_error());
}
```

script does not show any error.also query executed.but i didn't get my expected result.at the same i try this query in phpmyAdmin i got my expected result. i dont know the cause of this problem.
plz any one find the problem .
thanks

Comment: Since the query depends on a NOT EXISTS clause, have you checked that the last sub-select returns no records?

Comment: What do you mean exactly with *but i didn't get my expected result.* ? The message *"Query executed OK"* is not printed?

Answer (score 1):

> script does not show any error

Have you got error reporting enabled? Have you tested it with trigger_error() ?

> but i didn't get my expected result

What did you get?

What did you expect?

- and BTW, it'd be a lot more efficient to drop the sub-query from the select and use INSERT IGNORE (assuming id has a unique index).

C.